# CSS Grid element is expanding outside of the container

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm using CSS grid and attempting to do a layout with it. I have multiple levels of grids, as I'm using react and want a different layout on different pages. There doesn't seem to be a way to keep the inner grid from expanding outside the container that it is set to use by the parent grid, so the scrolling on it is messed up.

I'd rather not have to use hardcoded values for the offsets on the headers, as that's why I'm using grid in the first place. Any ideas on how to make this work properly? (I'm trying to make the scrollbar on the `.body` be the only part of the page that scrolls)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.mainheader {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
}


.page {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.page > div {
  padding: 16px;
}

.subheader {
  background: red;
}
.body {
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* This scroll does nothing, as the parent does not lock to the 1fr set in .app */
}
.footer {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="mainheader">This is the main header</div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="subheader">This is the subheader</div>
    <div class="body">
      <div>Body content #1</div>
      <div>Body content #2</div>
      <div>Body content #3</div>
      <div>Body content #4</div>
      <div>Body content #5</div>
      <div>Body content #6</div>
      <div>Body content #7</div>
      <div>Body content #8</div>
      <div>Body content #9</div>
      <div>Body content #10</div>
      <div>Body content #11</div>
      <div>Body content #12</div>
      <div>Body content #13</div>
      <div>Body content #14</div>
      <div>Body content #15</div>
      <div>Body content #16</div>
      <div>Body content #17</div>
      <div>Body content #18</div>
      <div>Body content #19</div>
      <div>Body content #20</div>
      <div>Body content #21</div>
      <div>Body content #22</div>
      <div>Body content #23</div>
      <div>Body content #24</div>
      <div>Body content #25</div>
      <div>Body content #26</div>
      <div>Body content #27</div>
      <div>Body content #28</div>
      <div>Body content #29</div>
      <div>Body content #30</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">This is the footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try set `min-height: fit-content` to `.page`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov min-height:0 should be enought

Comment: min-height: 0 did the trick!

Comment: @TemaniAfif, yes, your advice is good.

Answer (score -1):

a better way to do this would be with flex.
Here's how you can do it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mainheader {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
}


.page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 0;
}

.page > div {
  padding: 16px;
}

.subheader {
  background: red;
}

.body {
background: blue;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.footer {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="mainheader">This is the main header</div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="subheader">This is the subheader</div>
    <div class="body">
      <div>Body content #1</div>
      <div>Body content #2</div>
      <div>Body content #3</div>
      <div>Body content #4</div>
      <div>Body content #5</div>
      <div>Body content #6</div>
      <div>Body content #7</div>
      <div>Body content #8</div>
      <div>Body content #9</div>
      <div>Body content #10</div>
      <div>Body content #11</div>
      <div>Body content #12</div>
      <div>Body content #13</div>
      <div>Body content #14</div>
      <div>Body content #15</div>
      <div>Body content #16</div>
      <div>Body content #17</div>
      <div>Body content #18</div>
      <div>Body content #19</div>
      <div>Body content #20</div>
      <div>Body content #21</div>
      <div>Body content #22</div>
      <div>Body content #23</div>
      <div>Body content #24</div>
      <div>Body content #25</div>
      <div>Body content #26</div>
      <div>Body content #27</div>
      <div>Body content #28</div>
      <div>Body content #29</div>
      <div>Body content #30</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">This is the footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```